# Computer is slower on faster network

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, internet, internet-connection

I have a great and fast laptop, while using my University's wireless Internet connection.

Once I come home and plug in the LAN connection (which has much better download / upload speeds than the university's), my whole computer becomes slower.

Opening a tab takes much more time, loading a website etc. I used `traceroute` and it shows great ping times (better than university's). I am just going crazy, I think I have tried everything (changed DNS servers, still the same). What can I do?

I use Linux by the way. My router at home is Buffalo. Also, some time ago, everything was fine, I don't remember the time it started. I tried restarting router, still the same. In addition, it is slow I guess because CPU shows 100% a lot (when opening a tab for example).

Comment: Is your browser the one responsible for the 100% CPU or is there another process?

Comment: I have reworded your question, to add a little more clarity while reading. This being said, have you checked for either malware or automatic updates? Could it be possible that you have some process that's *hogging* the faster connection (and due to that, also using up your CPU time)? Also, what flavor of Linux are you using?

Comment: Have you tried using [Google's DNS Servers](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/): `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`. Can you show the output of the `top` command (while cpu is at 100%)?.

Comment: I tried every browser, still the same.

Comment: CPU at 100% is kind of a red flag and indicates that it is not the network. What do you see with top?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are mistaking response time with bandwidth.  Having quick response time does NOT necessarily translate into higher speed if you do not have the bandwidth to do anything.  I'll bet your ISP at home is throttling your total available bandwidth and thus you are getting the results you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but you are wrong. There are no problems on other computers or downloading huge torrents.

Answer (score 0):

Seems likely that your university network is blocking access to some botnet or virus that's on your computer, and your home network isn't...so you connect at home and (whatever it is) beats your network and computer to death.

Comment: Nope, checked the requests coming from computer (via wireshark)

Answer (score 0):

When you "plug in" into the LAN at home that sounds like an ethernet cable.  Does the link light on your Buffalo indicate the speed and duplex of your connection 10? 100? 1000? Mbps?    Use miitool or ethtool to see the connection status ... maybe your wired at home connection is only connecting at half-duplex.

Is your laptop at home also slow when using *wireless* relatively close to your Buffalo?

The router webpage should say how busy it is handling gateway duties.  Further, may be a roommate throttled down your laptop at home?

Is there an "always on" VPN in order to connect at school?  `ip route` should look altogether different at school than at home.

Comment: It seems it is full-duplex. Also, wireless is fine.

Comment: So you confirm your Linux laptop's network performance is fine at home over wireless but exhibits horrible performance over a Cat6 wired ethernet connection. What are the results of 'mii-tool eth0' and  'ethtool eth0'?

Comment: eth0: negotiated 100baseTx-FD flow-control, link ok

Comment: Turn wireless off on a fast performing machine in the house.  Disconnect your Cat5E cable from the back of your laptop and connect it to a machine that performs fine.  Leave the cable plugged into the same port on the switch.  Does the fast machine become slow?  The ethernet patch cable should say CATV, Cat5E, or Cat6.  It should not say Cat3 nor CatIII.